# JavaScript file extensions are renamed from *.js to *.j_

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project with asp.net core 2.2 and react.

Recently I sent a new version to my client, but I got the feedback that the browser window is blank always. I told my client to check the browser console for any fault messages.The browser was showing the following message:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

I was not able to reproduce this message, so I ask my client to sent back the project which is causing the problems to me. With the project of my client I was able to reproduce the fault. Furthermore I found all **JavaScript file extensions are renamed from *.js to *.j_**

[image: **enter image description here**]

After renaming the extension back to *.js the fault message is gone, and everything is working as expected.

What could be the reason for remaining the file extension of all JavaScript files? Could it be done by a browser possibly?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets from the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the mail server. Because of security reasons the mail server renamed the JavaScript files contained in the zip-file of the project to ***.j_**